# Pattern from ggpattern disappears in legend only in pdf or png output

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpattern

When I use the `ggpattern` package, it produces a great plot with a working legend in the Rstudio IDE. However, when I export to pdf or png, the legend fails to include two pattern types. Data for reproducible question at bottom of post.

```
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

p<-ggplot(Both)+
  geom_col_pattern(aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer,
                       pattern=Consumer,pattern_fill=Consumer),
           color="black",alpha=0.8)+
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c(rep(c('circle','stripe', 'crosshatch'),5))) 

p
```

[image]

Notice that all three patterns show up in the legend.
Now add output to pdf or png:

```
pdf("Predator_Comparison/Energy_Budget_Plot.pdf",width=12,height=9)
p
dev.off()

png("Predator_Comparison/Energy_Budget_Plot.png",width=12,height=9,units = "in",res=300)
p
dev.off()
```

[image]

Notice that the legend now only includes the 'circle' type pattern, but the other two aren't visible. Any thoughts as to what is going on here?

There are 15 matching warnings (presumably 1 for each legend box):

```
Warning messages:
1: convert_polygon_sf_to_polygon_df(): Not POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON: c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")
```

## Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggpattern_1.0.0 ggplot2_3.3.6  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3       pillar_1.7.0       compiler_4.2.2    
 [4] class_7.3-20       tools_4.2.2        digest_0.6.29     
 [7] memoise_2.0.1      lifecycle_1.0.1    tibble_3.1.7      
[10] gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_1.0.6       
[13] DBI_1.1.2          cli_3.3.0          rstudioapi_0.13   
[16] gridpattern_1.0.1  fastmap_1.1.0      e1071_1.7-11      
[19] withr_2.5.0        dplyr_1.0.9        generics_0.1.2    
[22] vctrs_0.4.1        classInt_0.4-7     grid_4.2.2        
[25] tidyselect_1.1.2   glue_1.6.2         sf_1.0-7          
[28] R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.3        purrr_0.3.4       
[31] farver_2.1.0       magrittr_2.0.3     units_0.8-0       
[34] scales_1.2.0       ellipsis_0.3.2     assertthat_0.2.1  
[37] colorspace_2.0-3   labeling_0.4.2     KernSmooth_2.23-20
[40] utf8_1.2.2         proxy_0.4-27       munsell_0.5.0     
[43] cachem_1.0.6       crayon_1.5.1
```

## Data

```
Both<-structure(list(Consumer = c("Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
"Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
"Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Phytoplankton", 
"Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
"Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
"Phytoplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
"Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
"Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
"Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
"Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
"Juvenile Salmon", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
"Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
"Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
"Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
"Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
"Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
"Mammals", "Mammals", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
"Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery"
), Donor = c("Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
"Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
"Detritus"), Prop = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.549707229476897, 
0.167643507074938, 0.177108578190667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0143826890253642, 
0.0829032868760895, 0.187199681369435, 0.377282871954272, 0.0317762383870992, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.23608971861909, 0.139938803079468, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.26740382187952, 0.0554921943314639, 0.0141169593098825, 
0.322048564282078, 0.0402201203747207, 0.0354709110190114, 0.0512084875597042, 
0, 0, 0.00419945182273723, 0.0186833956330583, 0.00371942571234938, 
0.413834007411829, 0.046934877854785, 0.209993132669013, 0.319007851986433, 
0.258124487510548, 0.410119996920118, 0.250820097844463, 0.256537937291491, 
0.0665270522130403, 0.000227877927707474, 2.19230238166815e-05, 
0.000223889868244159, 0.00400793137539267, 0.000719083654571443, 
0.0269857933847916, 0, 0, 0.000166958973997495, 0.000271211537513765, 
0.00452310090607862, 9.0161932259385e-05, 0.0192454776488071, 
0.0672607939569437, 0.0729410191750948, 0.0537692126845227, 0.191987174064799, 
0.0284458999742289, 0.0285257051611284, 0, 0.00119636947274399, 
4.85600349094982e-05, 0.0096441913441693, 0.0173677639651089, 
0, 0.0172469482122006, 0, 0, 6.35670556389205e-05, 0.000116027210051219, 
0.00429666731357137, 0.0199761039648904, 0.213659805295418, 0.387044582855991, 
0.0639149633556294, 0.397293293811269, 0, 0, 0.0546098316910703, 
0, 0.0316551932651675, 0.00390389142820152, 0.0172703473873986, 
0, 0, 0.013396290206477, 0, 0, 0.0457699126397193, 0.0126173967159077, 
0.0204905400541821, 0, 0.152368033925752, 0.00620262313406725, 
0.00576668120974208, 0.0367544950174518, 0.00885310370133351, 
0, 0.535495518082598, 0.207168991986137, 0.000721789625651111, 
3.85712132584874e-06, 0.00072113615732755, 0.155137071890671, 
0.0361919450355016, 0.0819991943267615, 0.0644369559479108, 0.00411713022515574, 
2.52615601695038e-05, 0.108173638197542, 0.000831127465284076, 
0.00307815674367491, 0.00899885965825438, 0.104679644151026, 
0.331317128245986, 0.0632217972862738, 0.246257336982954, 0.0681378872872917, 
0.0466978253528048, 4.54591320499687e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0.00808633562706585, 
0.13467041631803, 0, 0.0783454323828845, 0.64847898466886, 0.0135253413432805, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.592305587668469, 0.432622464206602, 
0.185384809959524, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0123632682828704, 0.217444293340073, 
0.137061156612281, 0.0740408314288209, 0.000450958829355742, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00694691696783311, 0.0912850271659293, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.126482511704573, 0.0572626281977687, 0.126538814376875, 
0.251620851502401, 0.0293803850334056, 0.0438564810457525, 0.0398206261279957, 
0, 0, 0.0193501630791624, 0.00699759838742462, 0.0133454293528453, 
0.103991034069577, 0.0587719702349853, 0.323913920639485, 0.363680140068061, 
0.174901149896074, 0.525917573675966, 0.380592408232399, 0.143352480934178, 
0.114719759307649, 0.000716895919481306, 0.00036334504821922, 
0.000827030789646068, 0.00466965533077688, 0.000145950039388543, 
0.0583761853756203, 0, 0, 0.000103198641446566, 0.000667606167556876, 
0.0145316852020556, 0.00277406302102769, 0.0217707477205417, 
0.0567662230827084, 0.0997119449168991, 0.0474318758721208, 0.189131157773477, 
0.041973522276621, 0.0134114434389902, 3.5516530117129e-05, 0.0201410109416757, 
0.00341915171668221, 0.092903868588999, 0.1051958785497, 0.01838542557169, 
0.194834783487864, 0.056373477474872, 0.000761098008172345, 0.0258662949582249, 
0.0118196224353152, 0.00589559147923082, 0.0102581715983585, 
0.1223715463388, 0.304659678104167, 0.0376880245027111, 0.365620556732433, 
0, 0, 0.0304411575973729, 0.153068761838369, 0.0275540194533818, 
0.0369598640935704, 0.0183898976577045, 0, 0, 0.0224593614490102, 
0, 0, 0.0205323710977207, 0.0356179306572834, 0.0388436806752666, 
0, 0.237769379442536, 0.000148162462610862, 0.00122497901109871, 
0.0111299830615506, 0.0323568170881112, 0, 0.727171320686274, 
0.27859489874831, 0.000280478691985259, 0.000223568607081643, 
0.000382333975078339, 0.0711087350275364, 0.00494860881474787, 
0.0272518987812531, 0.00302390077335372, 0.00169278643426349, 
7.4551559576518e-06, 0.0475617036599278, 0.00077680863962975, 
0.208808691833186, 0.00935660496042811, 0.102618573383442, 0.315878733012937, 
0.058173579216078, 0.130457508883227, 0.0650956639065043, 0.00379652830385642, 
4.28802555692741e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0.00153878838616774, 0.114479713016713, 
0, 0.0627395643309926, 0.50988452114204, 0.00360431782394685, 
0), MHW = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), levels = c("pre", "post"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you use cairo graphics (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/cairo)?

I.e. `cairo_pdf()` and png(device = "cairo") both work on my system:

```r
Both <- structure(list(Consumer = c("Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
                                  "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
                                  "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
                                  "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
                                  "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
                                  "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
                                  "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
                                  "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
                                  "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
                                  "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
                                  "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Jack Mackerel", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
                                  "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
                                  "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
                                  "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
                                  "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
                                  "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
                                  "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
                                  "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", "Phytoplankton", 
                                  "Phytoplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
                                  "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", 
                                  "Zooplankton", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
                                  "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", 
                                  "Gelatinous", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", 
                                  "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
                                  "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", 
                                  "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Forage Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
                                  "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", 
                                  "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", "Juvenile Salmon", 
                                  "Juvenile Salmon", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
                                  "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", "Rockfish", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", 
                                  "Jack Mackerel", "Jack Mackerel", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", 
                                  "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Hake", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Juvenile Fish", 
                                  "Juvenile Fish", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
                                  "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", "Benthic", 
                                  "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", 
                                  "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Seabirds", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
                                  "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", "Mammals", 
                                  "Mammals", "Mammals", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", 
                                  "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery", "Fishery"
), Donor = c("Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus", "Zooplankton", "Gelatinous", "Krill", "Forage Fish", 
             "Misc. Fish", "Juvenile Fish", "Rockfish", "Hake", "Benthic", 
             "Detritus"), Prop = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.549707229476897, 
                                   0.167643507074938, 0.177108578190667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0143826890253642, 
                                   0.0829032868760895, 0.187199681369435, 0.377282871954272, 0.0317762383870992, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.23608971861909, 0.139938803079468, 0, 0, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.26740382187952, 0.0554921943314639, 0.0141169593098825, 
                                   0.322048564282078, 0.0402201203747207, 0.0354709110190114, 0.0512084875597042, 
                                   0, 0, 0.00419945182273723, 0.0186833956330583, 0.00371942571234938, 
                                   0.413834007411829, 0.046934877854785, 0.209993132669013, 0.319007851986433, 
                                   0.258124487510548, 0.410119996920118, 0.250820097844463, 0.256537937291491, 
                                   0.0665270522130403, 0.000227877927707474, 2.19230238166815e-05, 
                                   0.000223889868244159, 0.00400793137539267, 0.000719083654571443, 
                                   0.0269857933847916, 0, 0, 0.000166958973997495, 0.000271211537513765, 
                                   0.00452310090607862, 9.0161932259385e-05, 0.0192454776488071, 
                                   0.0672607939569437, 0.0729410191750948, 0.0537692126845227, 0.191987174064799, 
                                   0.0284458999742289, 0.0285257051611284, 0, 0.00119636947274399, 
                                   4.85600349094982e-05, 0.0096441913441693, 0.0173677639651089, 
                                   0, 0.0172469482122006, 0, 0, 6.35670556389205e-05, 0.000116027210051219, 
                                   0.00429666731357137, 0.0199761039648904, 0.213659805295418, 0.387044582855991, 
                                   0.0639149633556294, 0.397293293811269, 0, 0, 0.0546098316910703, 
                                   0, 0.0316551932651675, 0.00390389142820152, 0.0172703473873986, 
                                   0, 0, 0.013396290206477, 0, 0, 0.0457699126397193, 0.0126173967159077, 
                                   0.0204905400541821, 0, 0.152368033925752, 0.00620262313406725, 
                                   0.00576668120974208, 0.0367544950174518, 0.00885310370133351, 
                                   0, 0.535495518082598, 0.207168991986137, 0.000721789625651111, 
                                   3.85712132584874e-06, 0.00072113615732755, 0.155137071890671, 
                                   0.0361919450355016, 0.0819991943267615, 0.0644369559479108, 0.00411713022515574, 
                                   2.52615601695038e-05, 0.108173638197542, 0.000831127465284076, 
                                   0.00307815674367491, 0.00899885965825438, 0.104679644151026, 
                                   0.331317128245986, 0.0632217972862738, 0.246257336982954, 0.0681378872872917, 
                                   0.0466978253528048, 4.54591320499687e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0.00808633562706585, 
                                   0.13467041631803, 0, 0.0783454323828845, 0.64847898466886, 0.0135253413432805, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.592305587668469, 0.432622464206602, 
                                   0.185384809959524, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0123632682828704, 0.217444293340073, 
                                   0.137061156612281, 0.0740408314288209, 0.000450958829355742, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00694691696783311, 0.0912850271659293, 0, 
                                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.126482511704573, 0.0572626281977687, 0.126538814376875, 
                                   0.251620851502401, 0.0293803850334056, 0.0438564810457525, 0.0398206261279957, 
                                   0, 0, 0.0193501630791624, 0.00699759838742462, 0.0133454293528453, 
                                   0.103991034069577, 0.0587719702349853, 0.323913920639485, 0.363680140068061, 
                                   0.174901149896074, 0.525917573675966, 0.380592408232399, 0.143352480934178, 
                                   0.114719759307649, 0.000716895919481306, 0.00036334504821922, 
                                   0.000827030789646068, 0.00466965533077688, 0.000145950039388543, 
                                   0.0583761853756203, 0, 0, 0.000103198641446566, 0.000667606167556876, 
                                   0.0145316852020556, 0.00277406302102769, 0.0217707477205417, 
                                   0.0567662230827084, 0.0997119449168991, 0.0474318758721208, 0.189131157773477, 
                                   0.041973522276621, 0.0134114434389902, 3.5516530117129e-05, 0.0201410109416757, 
                                   0.00341915171668221, 0.092903868588999, 0.1051958785497, 0.01838542557169, 
                                   0.194834783487864, 0.056373477474872, 0.000761098008172345, 0.0258662949582249, 
                                   0.0118196224353152, 0.00589559147923082, 0.0102581715983585, 
                                   0.1223715463388, 0.304659678104167, 0.0376880245027111, 0.365620556732433, 
                                   0, 0, 0.0304411575973729, 0.153068761838369, 0.0275540194533818, 
                                   0.0369598640935704, 0.0183898976577045, 0, 0, 0.0224593614490102, 
                                   0, 0, 0.0205323710977207, 0.0356179306572834, 0.0388436806752666, 
                                   0, 0.237769379442536, 0.000148162462610862, 0.00122497901109871, 
                                   0.0111299830615506, 0.0323568170881112, 0, 0.727171320686274, 
                                   0.27859489874831, 0.000280478691985259, 0.000223568607081643, 
                                   0.000382333975078339, 0.0711087350275364, 0.00494860881474787, 
                                   0.0272518987812531, 0.00302390077335372, 0.00169278643426349, 
                                   7.4551559576518e-06, 0.0475617036599278, 0.00077680863962975, 
                                   0.208808691833186, 0.00935660496042811, 0.102618573383442, 0.315878733012937, 
                                   0.058173579216078, 0.130457508883227, 0.0650956639065043, 0.00379652830385642, 
                                   4.28802555692741e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0.00153878838616774, 0.114479713016713, 
                                   0, 0.0627395643309926, 0.50988452114204, 0.00360431782394685, 
                                   0), MHW = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                         2L, 2L), levels = c("pre", "post"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                               -300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

p<-ggplot(Both)+
  geom_col_pattern(aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer,
                       pattern=Consumer,pattern_fill=Consumer),
                   color="black",alpha=0.8)+
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_pattern_manual(values=c(rep(c('circle','stripe', 'crosshatch'),5))) 

cairo_pdf()
p
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2

png(type = "cairo")
p
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

[image: example.png]

(I can't upload the pdf to SO, but the plot looks the same)

Comment: Yes this does work for me as well. This is the preferred answer because it doesn't require fiddling with the scale_factor!

Comment: Glad you solved your issue :)  Thanks for including all of the required info (e.g. `sessionInfo()`)

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice from one of the package developers: https://github.com/coolbutuseless/ggpattern/issues/86
I tried playing with `theme(legend.key.size = unit(x, 'cm'))` and `pattern_key_scale_factor = x`, where I varied x by trial and error.

Using `pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.5` worked in my specific case:

```
p<-ggplot(Both)+
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(y=Prop,x=MHW,fill=Consumer,
        pattern=Consumer,pattern_fill=Consumer),
    color="black",alpha=0.8,
    pattern_key_scale_factor=.5)+ ## the addition that solved my issue
  facet_wrap(~Donor,nrow=2)+
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90)#,
    # legend.key.size = unit(2, 'cm') # this didn't seem to help me, but worth playing with
    )+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="Proportion")+
  scale_pattern_manual(
    values=c(rep(c('circle','stripe', 'crosshatch'),5))
    ) 

pdf("Predator_Comparison/Energy_Budget_Plot.pdf",width=12,height=9)
p
dev.off()
```

[image]